# How to Union different tables from two different databases?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I currently find myself stuck in a situation where I have to union different tables from two different databases. The other database served as an archive for records which are no longer accessed but still needed for reports. I am developing an interface where they could view historical reports. I am using MS SQL Server. Is it possible to do this?

Any help would be highly appreciated...

Comment: Does your user have access to both databases? If so, just query the tables e.g. `[database].[schema].[tablename]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use three part naming convention

```
ex:
database name:A
Schema name:dbo
table name test
```

You can refer like
select top  10* from a.dbo.test

Similarly to union two different tables in two different databases,you can do like below

```
select top  10* from a.dbo.test
union
select top  10* from b.dbo.test
```

if those databases are in different server ( say server1 and server 2),you need to create linked server and you can access like below

```
select top  10* from server1.a.dbo.test
union
select top  10* from server2.a.dbo.test
```

Comment: Thank you for this one.. it really help a lot. :)